# BSON ObjectID from string

Tags: mongodb, sinatra

`BSON::ObjectId.from_string(params[:_id])`

I'm learning Sinatra and I keep getting `BSON::InvalidObjectId Exception: illegal ObjectId format` as an error. I've passed it actual strings instead of a variable but it keeps throwing an error. Why would the `from_string` method not accept `"stringy"` as an argument.

```
get "/venue/:_id" do
  object_id = BSON::ObjectId.from_string(params[:_id])
  @venue = VENUES.find_one({ :_id => object_id }) #VENUES is my coll
  haml :venue
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB an ObjectId is a specific data format with specific information contained within it. The information that it contains is displayed in hex format when output as a string.

Your input string of "stringy" isn't a hex representation and could never guarantee to be coalesced into a valid ObjectId, this is rejected.

The check used in the MongoDB ruby driver to see if a string can be turned into an ObjectId(which should be what Sinatra is using) is available [on github](https://github.com/mongodb/bson-ruby/blob/master/lib/bson/object_id.rb#L284). You can read more about what makes up a MongoDB ObjectId in [their documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

Comment: Thanks for that; however, I've read most of their docs on `from_string` and its not immediately apparent how i access one specific model from the url if this doesnt work. The tutorial I'm following has this exact line of code for a model show page [link to tutorial](http://spf13.com/presentation/building-your-first-mongodb-app-oscon-2012/) specifically slide 106. How else am I supposed to retrieve the document from the db?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you have a mongodb id as string and you need the corresponding object from the database.

So how about that: `res = coll.find(:_id => BSON::ObjectId(id)).first` where id is you id as string.

Here is my full working example:

```
require 'mongo'
include Mongo

Mongo::Logger.logger.level = ::Logger::FATAL

db = Client.new([ "localhost:27017" ], :database => "db")
coll = db[:testCollection]
coll.insert_one("paramA" => "xyz", "paramB" => "dsafdsaf")
coll.insert_one("paramA" => "1234", "paramB" => "111111")

obj = coll.find(:paramA => "1234").first

p "your id as string"
id = obj[:_id].to_s
p id

p "result"
res = coll.find(:_id => BSON::ObjectId(id)).first
p res
```

Using the mongo version **2.1.0**. (Which is really important since they switch the syntax quite a lot)

I personally use [mongomapper](http://mongomapper.com/) since it's much simpler with an ORM mapper, but thats up to you.

Comment: Thanks but I actually wanted to use an integer ID to reference the document in the collection itself. For instance, using SQL, i would write `@venue = Venue.find(params[:id])` however, I cant seem to do the same without specific knowledge of the BSON object id itself. [Link to tutorial](http://spf13.com/presentation/building-your-first-mongodb-app-oscon-2012/) that I'm following is here. Page 106 will explain everything if you could take a look at it.

Comment: O.o now I'm confused - can you please update your question with how your code looks (Venue class, your sinatra route) but it should be this -> `obj = coll.find(:paramA => "1234").first`

Comment: @Jeff and your mongo version is 2.1.0?

Comment: I just typed in `db.version()` and it says 3.0.6. If this was deprecated, could you tell me what the updated method would look like? Im very confused at this mongo stuff coming from SQL

Comment: Sorry I'm not talking about your database version, I'm talking about the mongo gem version

Comment: The gemfile itself says `mongo` but the gemfile.lock says `mongo (1.12.3)`

Comment: @Jeff well I check it when I'm back on a computer if I can repoduce it

Comment: @Jeff I just build it with `mongo (1.12.3)` (it's perfectly normal not to set a fix version in your Gemfile) and `BSON::ObjectId.from_string(id)` works fine so my best guess is that you have a problem with passing the Id to your frontend and back

Comment: I've checked the value in debugger and it is an integer. I guess the tutorial I was following is outdated and they have since changed the from_string method to only take formatted input. Thanks for your help. Ill just pass on learning mongo for now haha

Comment: @Jeff ^^ as said earlier I would recommended to start with something like http://mongomapper.com/ it's way simpler to interact with your database ;D